# Get random directory

Tags: php

I have several directories in one main directory. All I want to do is use php to echo a random directory from this list of directories every time the page refreshes.

I have been working with the following code but with no success:

```
$base_dir = 'images/';
function get_random_dir($base_dir)
    {
        $dirs = glob(sprintf($base_dir),GLOB_ONLYDIR);
        return empty($dirs) ? null : $dirs[array_rand($dirs)];
    }
echo get_random_dir($dirs);
```

At the moment this returns nothing. If anyone could help me out that would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$base_dir = "images/";
function get_random_dir($base_dir) {
    $dirs = scandir($base_dir);
    return empty($dirs)?null:$dirs[rand(2,count($dirs)-1)];
}
```

This should work. The rand starts from `2` because `0` is `.` and `1` is `..`